# How to enable unicode support (ICU) in OS X's sqlite3 command?

Tags: macos, unicode, sqlite, icu

I understand that the sqlite3 command (as well as the lib version) can be built with a statically linked ICU lib to fully support unicode operations. It should also be possible to dynamically load an ICU extension.

But neither of these seem to be the case with OS X's sqlite3 command (as of 10.10.5).

Here's the test I'm using to determine ICU presence:

```
SELECT upper('ä');
```

This should result in "Ä" if ICU is used by the engine. "ä" indicates missing ICU support. Is that a valid test?

Apart from compiling a new command and probably dylib, too, is there another way to enable unicode support so that upper, lower and comparisons know about unicode letters and not just ASCII?

Comment: Have you built the extension? What's the error you get from `sqlite3_load_extension()`?

Comment: Yes, I've built it. It's here: http://files.tempel.org/RB/SQLite%20Extensions%20Demo.zip - the error is simply "Error: no such function: load_extension"

Comment: This problem has been annoying me since 2012. I reported a bug to Apple, which they closed two years later without fixing.

Comment: Hi I rebuild your project for macOS 10.13 but when I loaded it I got the error "Error: dlopen(./sqlite3_icu_extension.dylib.dylib, 10): image not found" Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: @Qiulang There are two ".dylib" in the file name. That looks wrong.

Comment: Oh sorry I sent the wrong error message, it is Error: dlopen(./sqlite3_icu_extension.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 ./sqlite3_icu_extension.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
 /Users/qiulang/Downloads/SQLite Extensions Demo/SQLite ICU Extension/sqlite3_icu_extension.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: I did not know suffix will be added automatically when I first tried it. So the "real" error was "wrong architecture " when running  "sqlite> .load ./sqlite3_icu_extension". I already set it to "standard architecture 64 bit" for macOS when I built your project.

Comment: This is not the place to teach you how to build 64 bit libs, but I've updated my demo project to include a 64 bit build now.